# How to calculate http request&response size in rust hyper 0.14

Tags: rust, hyper

I'm writing a gateway is hyper and looking for a way to calculate the size of http request&response size(bytes) in hyper 0.14. as you know the body of request&response is a stream, so is there any middleware or any other solution for this problem?

Comment: The size may be given in the `content-size` header, but that's not mandatory and if it's not present there is no way to know without retrieving the body and counting the bytes you got.

Comment: The body of request&response in hyper is stream, the easy solution is to fetch stream till end and count the size, but it can lean to overflow. the true way is to count chunk of data in each stream poll and return sum. but I want to know how we can do it in hyper?

Comment: Why do you think _that_ cannot overflow? If you want to prevent overflow in any case, use a bigint.

Comment: I'm not talking about overflow of size variable. I meant if we load all content to be able to get it's real size, the content will occupy memory, think about 1000 request per second with1G response size, we need 1TB memory just for loading responses.